# When I work with materials and shading, suddenly the app closes

Tags: node-editor, shaders

When I work with materials and shading the app suddenly closes. Is there something wrong with my pc 
or blender?

Comment: Most likely your hardware (issue with your graphics card), see https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ and I'd suggest update your driver.

Comment: thank you for it. I will check that.